# how to run FPGrowth in sparklyr package

Tags: r, sparklyr, fpgrowth

I have the data "`li`" and I want to run the algorithm FPGrowth, but I don't know how

```
set.seed(123)

# make fake data
li <- list()
for(i in 1:10) li[[i]] <- make.unique(letters[sample(1:26,sample(5:20,1),rep = T)])
 

require(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local",version = "3.0.1")


df <- copy_to(sc,  **....??????what should be here??????...**  )
            fp_growth_model <- ml_fpgrowth(df)
```

there is a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59507461/fpgrowth-association-rules-using-sparklyr) but it doesn't work, i get the error

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = "2.3")
tb <- tibble::tibble(items=c("a b c", "a b", "c f g", "b c"))

df <- copy_to(sc, tb)  %>% 
 mutate(items = split(items, "\\\\s+"))

Error in mutate(., items = split(items, "\\\\s+")) : 
  could not find function "mutate"
```

/// plyr::mutate

```
df <- copy_to(sc, tb)  %>% 
  plyr::mutate(items = split(items, "\\\\s+"))

Error in sdf_import.default(x, sc, name, memory, repartition, overwrite,  : 
  table tb already exists (pass overwrite = TRUE to overwrite)
```

/// SparkR::mutate

```
df <- copy_to(sc, tb)  %>% 
  SparkR::mutate(items = split(items, "\\\\s+"))

Error in sdf_import.default(x, sc, name, memory, repartition, overwrite,  : 
  table tb already exists (pass overwrite = TRUE to overwrite)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code example from the mentioned answer works. You get two errors the first because `mutate` was not loaded. The second because the object `tb` was already loaded into Spark.

Try running the following code from a new session:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sparklyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

tb <- tibble::tibble(items=c("a b c", "a b", "c f g", "b c"))

df <- copy_to(sc, tb)  %>% 
  mutate(items = split(items, "\\\\s+"))

fp_growth_model <- ml_fpgrowth(df)

ml_association_rules(fp_growth_model)
ml_freq_itemsets(fp_growth_model)
```

To execute FP-growth with your dataset `li`, you need to change the format.
The function `ml_fpgrowth` requires a SparkDataFrame with a column of lists containing the sequences. You cannot transfer an R DataFrame with lists directly to Spark. First, you create a SparkDataFrame with sequences as a String and then generate the lists with `mutate` and `split` functions.

Here is the code applied to your data.

```
> tb_li <- tibble(items=sapply(li, function(x) paste(x, collapse=" ")))
> tb_li
# A tibble: 10 x 1
   items                                            
   <chr>                                            
 1 o s n c j r v k e t n.1 v.1 y z e.1 s.1 y.1 y.2 i
 2 c h z g j i s d n q k g.1 u l o j.1 m            
 3 i i.1 j w u g u.1 f y b e                        
 4 l m r a y y.1 f u o i o.1 z                      
 5 p t f k h v v.1 g p.1 q v.2 r q.1 b d m          
 6 v s y t v.1 y.1 n y.2 w                          
 7 h p l y n c n.1                                  
 8 g c w v z o u e h s j r j.1 l b j.2 v.1          
 9 l t n q n.1 v c h n.2 s o x q.1 w k g o.1 w.1 z  
10 n g j e f p x u w k
```

Transfer data to Spark and generate the lists:

```
> df_li <- copy_to(sc, tb_li, overwrite = TRUE) %>%
+   mutate(items = split(items, "\\\\s+"))
> df_li
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 1]
   items      
   <list>     
 1 <list [19]>
 2 <list [17]>
 3 <list [11]>
 4 <list [12]>
 5 <list [16]>
 6 <list [9]> 
 7 <list [7]> 
 8 <list [17]>
 9 <list [19]>
10 <list [10]>
```

The data is ready to be used by the model like the example above.

```
> fp_growth_model_li <- ml_fpgrowth(df_li)

> ml_association_rules(fp_growth_model_li)
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 4]
   antecedent consequent confidence  lift
   <list>     <list>          <dbl> <dbl>
 1 <list [4]> <list [1]>          1     2
 2 <list [3]> <list [1]>          1     2
 3 <list [3]> <list [1]>          1     2
 4 <list [3]> <list [1]>          1     2
 5 <list [5]> <list [1]>          1     2
 6 <list [5]> <list [1]>          1     2
 7 <list [3]> <list [1]>          1     2
 8 <list [3]> <list [1]>          1     2
 9 <list [3]> <list [1]>          1     2
10 <list [3]> <list [1]>          1     2
# ... with more rows

> ml_freq_itemsets(fp_growth_model_li)
# Source: spark<?> [?? x 2]
   items       freq
   <list>     <dbl>
 1 <list [1]>     3
 2 <list [2]>     3
 3 <list [3]>     3
 4 <list [2]>     3
 5 <list [1]>     5
 6 <list [2]>     3
 7 <list [3]>     3
 8 <list [3]>     3
 9 <list [4]>     3
10 <list [2]>     4
# ... with more rows
```